# System is set to English, Nodejs package defaults to Polish

Tags: kubuntu, 19.10

I'm Polish. I've selected Polish keyboard layout during installation, everything else I want to be in English, however. British English is the only language present in language settings.

However, I just got a npm package (`yargs`) that prints out its help info in Polish.

### How do I set the entirety of my system to English?

As requested in comments, output of `locale -a && locale`:

```
rijndael@rd:~$ locale -a && locale
C
C.UTF-8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IL
en_IL.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
pl_PL.utf8
POSIX
LANG=pl_PL.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_GB
LC_CTYPE="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_TIME=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_NAME=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Show us `locale -a && locale` commands output

Comment: @Gryu Added to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set all your locales to English in the next way:

```
sudo update-locale LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8
```

Then apply changes by the next command execution:

```
. /etc/default/locale
```

But you could also change them one by one using almost the same command:

```
sudo update-locale LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
```

In this case only `LANG` locale will be changed.

Don't forget to apply changes by `. /etc/default/locale` command execution. The dot `.` is important part of the command.